# Testing requireJS methods async with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs, jasmine

I am trying to test a function that requires a module using **jasmine** and **requirejs**.
Here is a dummy code:

```
define("testModule", function() {
    return 123;
});
var test = function() {
    require(['testModule'], function(testModule) {
        return testModule + 1;
    });
}
describe("Async requirejs test", function() {
    it("should works", function() {
        expect(test()).toBe(124);
    });
});
```

It fails, because it is an async method. How can I perform a test with it?

*Note: I dont want to change my code, just my tests `describe` function.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing of an asynchronous stuff check `runs()`, `waits()` and `waitsFor()`:

https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs

Though this way looks a bit ugly as for me, therefore you could also consider following options.

**1.** I'd recommend you to try [**jasmine.async**](https://github.com/derickbailey/jasmine.async) that allows you to write asynchronous test cases in this way:

```
// Run an async expectation
async.it("did stuff", function(done) {
    // Simulate async code:
    setTimeout(function() {
        expect(1).toBe(1);
        // All async stuff done, and spec asserted
        done();
    });
});
```

---

**2.** Also you can run your tests inside `require`'s callback:

```
require([
    'testModule',
    'anotherTestModule'
], function(testModule, anotherTestModule) {

    describe('My Great Modules', function() {

        describe('testModule', function() {
            it('should be defined', function() {
                expect(testModule).toBeDefined();
            });
        });

        describe('anotherTestModule', function() {
            it('should be defined', function() {
                expect(anoterTestModule).toBeDefined();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

**3.** Another point is I guess that this code is not working as you're expecting:

```
var test = function() {
    require(['testModule'], function(testModule) {
        return testModule + 1;
    });
};
```

Because if you call `test()`, it won't return you `testModule + 1`.