# Why doesn't my Angular test $scope have the method defined on it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, requirejs, jasmine

For some reason the scope I'm injecting isn't getting populated, actually this might be somewhat obvious, a `console.log` statement revealed the controller isn't actually being executed until after the tests have run, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it. **update:**, I dumped `Insert` and it appears to be an empty object, which is probably not the right thing...

```
define([
'angular-mocks',
'controllers/insert'],
function( mocks ) {
'use strict';

describe('Controller: Insert', function () {
    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('pasteyApp'));

    var Insert,scope,location,pastes;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ( $injector, $controller, $rootScope ) {
        pastes     = $injector.get('pastes');
        location   = $injector.get('$location');
        scope      = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.code = 'package Foo::Bar;',
        Insert     = $controller('Insert', {
            $scope:    scope,
            $location: location,
            pastes:    pastes,
        });
    }));


    it('has code', function () {
        expect( scope.code ).toBe('package Foo::Bar;');
        scope.$apply();
    });

    it('updates location', function () {
        scope.view();
        expect( location.path() ).not.toBe('');
        expect( location.path() ).toBe('...');
        expect( pastes ).toBe( {} );
    });
});

});
```

`conrollers/insert`

```
define([
'crypto.MD5',
'angular',
'services',
], function() {
'use strict';

return ['$scope', '$location', 'pastes', function ( $scope, $location, pastes ) {
    $scope.view = function( ) {
        if ( $scope.code ) {
            // boo hex, really want urlsafe base64
            var digest = Crypto.MD5( $scope.code ).toString();
            console.log( digest );
            pastes[digest] = $scope.code;
        }
        $location.path( digest );
    };
}];
});
```

`controllers`

```
define([
    'app',
    'services',
], function ( app ) {
    'use strict';


    return app
            .controller('Insert', ['$scope','$injector', function( $scope, $injector ) {
                    require(['controllers/insert'], function( insert ) {
                            $injector.invoke( insert, this, { '$scope': $scope });
                    })
            }])
            .controller('Render', ['$scope','$injector', function( $scope, $injector ) {
                    require(['controllers/render'], function( render ) {
                            $injector.invoke( render, this, { '$scope': $scope });
                    });
            }])
            ;
});
```

the actual error

```
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux) Controller: Insert updates location FAILED
    TypeError: Object #<Scope> has no method 'view'
        at null.<anonymous>   (/home/xenoterracide/dev/Pastey/test/spec/controllers/insert.js:33:10)
```

Comment: I don't see any code that calls `angular.controller('Insert', ...)`

Comment: @BrianGenisio added my `controllers.js` [here's the entire code base](https://bitbucket.org/xenoterracide/pastey-frontend/src/dc3a8cb5c8d655129d94dbdfa8604bfcdf3c9801/)

Comment: Thanks.  Now, I don't see any place where "controllers" is required in the requirement chain of your tests.  I see it requiring "controllers/insert", but where is the test calling the `app.controller` code that registers your controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem.  Since `require()` is asynchronous and your Jasmine test is not, 'require/insert' function hasn't been executed by the time your specs are run.  You need to find a way within Jasmine to wait for require to complete before you execute your `it()` blocks.

This is why the controller IS an object, but nothing exists on it yet.  You are clearly registering everything properly (or else `$controller()` would throw) but not waiting long enough for require.js to do its job.

Looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552815/testing-requirejs-methods-async-with-jasmine) has a good handle on what you need to do.

Comment: shouldn't defines dependencies ensure the scripts are all loaded? tried wrapping with `run()` to no success

Comment: ok, `wait(100)` at the end of the before works, I imagine at the beginning of `it()` would too.

Comment: Perhaps it is loaded, but `require()` will be asynchronous to avoid order-of-operation bugs.  If it is true that the content is loaded, then `wait(0)` will probably work as well... just enough to let the event loop work through its pending actions.  But if you are still waiting to download the file, then `wait(100)` could cause timing test failures.

Comment: As a side note, I look at this and wonder what the advantage is of using require.js with Angular.  Angular already has a module system, and require.js adds a layer of complexity where I don't understand the benefit.  I certainly may be missing something, but I just don't understand the combination.

Comment: presumably asynchronous script loading, but I'm not 100% sure I'm convinced it's worth it either. This has been an experiment of learning the technologies.

Comment: I see.  That makes sense.  As my Angular project has gotten larger, I have hundreds of files.  If I were to asynchronously load them all, I'd have about 90 asynchronous GET calls on startup, and several more as I navigate.  So I just concatenate all my files together using a grunt task.  I pre-process/concatenate my templates for the same reason.  For large dependencies that I want to async load, I just use script.js for a simple/small dependency loader.

Comment: well of course this doesn't preclude concatenation when deploying to production, figuring out how to swap to cdn urls and concatenate code I wrote is coming up, after I write persistence.